# How get Image from ImageStream?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm getting ImageStream on CaptureImageAvailable event.
On ContentReadyEventArgs I have ImageStream.

I try copy this Stream to Image through BitmapImage:

```
Image cameraImage=new Image();
BitmapImage bImage=new BitmapImage();
    private void CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, ContentReadyEventArgs e)
    {

        bImage.SetSource(e.ImageStream);
        cameraImage.Source = bImage;
    }
```

but I have error on step bImage.SetSource(e.ImageStream);

How I should read this ImageStream?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you specify the error?

Comment: http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/07/31-days-of-mango-day-7-raw-camera-data/  - this might help

Comment: I need use Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()

Comment: Could you please show more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign the `Source` property if you are not on the main thread. And in this case, you aren't. To do that, simply force invoking it using `Dispatcher`

```
Image cameraImage=new Image();
BitmapImage bImage=new BitmapImage();

private void CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, ContentReadyEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
    {
        bImage.SetSource(e.ImageStream);
        cameraImage.Source = bImage;
    });
}
```

In case you are not inside a page (e.g. you are inside view-model or some other non-UI class), use the following syntax:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
{
    /* ... */
});
```